# Which CDN hosts the Google Code Prettify CSS file?

Tags: cdn, google-code-prettify

I've found the JS file on cloudflare, however the CSS file is nowhere to be found. Any ideas ?

Note: I don't want to link directly to the SVN repository and I don't want to use dropbox.

Answer (score 4):

HAve you checked this ?

this site has a lot of resources( js )

**http://cdnjs.com/**

[image]

Comment: Ryan from cdnjs here. Here's a direct link to the library page: http://cdnjs.com/libraries/prettify

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/google-code-prettify/prettify.css